# Acceso a un API Problema con CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema para realizar llamadas a una API. La aplicacion se encuentra dentro de la intranet, pero el servidor no tiene un servidor estandard (no existe un nodejs, o apache) donde pueda realizar cambios, sino que ha sido programada, y es una aplicacion .exe la encargada de la gestion de la web en los puertos.

En teoria, los desarrolladores podemos hacer llamadas a la API en el servidor, pero cuando se ejecuta la web desde otro equipo dentro de la intranet, tenemos problemas con CORS.

Hay algun modo de poder bypasearlo?

Esta es la peticion

```
function login(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/Users/Login?callback=?", true, "user", "password");
xhr.responseType = 'jsonp';
xhr.onload = function(){
    if (status==200){
        var resultsText = xhr.response;
        var results = JSON.parse(resultsText);
    }else{
        console.log("error");
    }        
}
xhr.send();
```

}

He probado a cambiar el tipo de respuesta por jsonp, pero no funciona. Alguna idea?

El error que recibo es...

en IE

```
SCRIPT5022: InvalidAccessError
```

and in firefox

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/apiGUI/Results?callback=?. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega o haz pantallazos de las cabeceras de petición y respuesta, o cualquier otra excepción que tengas

Comment: *el servidor no tiene un servidor estandard donde pueda realizar cambios, sino que ha sido programada para ser servida.* ¿Puedes arreglar esa frase? No entiendo bien a qué te refieres

Comment: tienes que habilitar en el servidor las peticiones de tus clientes.. el CORS es problema de recursos cruzado

Comment: Vale... pero como?

Comment: Esto se puede arreglar tanto en la API, como en el servidor web. eso depende de las capacidades que tengas y donde prefieras.

Comment: como comentaba... no tengo acceso al servidor, porque no hay servidor. Modificar la API, lo veo que puede ser demasiado complicado.

Comment: Un navegador es un cliente y la aplicación que responde a las llamadas HTTP es un servidor, sea un Apache o una aplicación que has creado tú que simplemente escucha el puerto 80. Si tienes acceso al código fuente de la aplicación puedes añadir el header necesario

Comment: No puedo hacer una modificacion en esa parte del codigo fuente. Necesitaria hacerlo de otra forma... quiza recogiendo el json localmente y poniendolo en otra app que lo sirviera, por ejemplo...